# Spring integration amqp adding headers repetitively

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-amqp

We have been using spring integration core  and spring integration amqp along with rabbitm-mq for a long time now. Our services also used dead lettering mechanism by using x-death header and amaqp-expiration header   It used to work fine until now when we decied to upgrade the version of spring-integration .

Prior version : 5.0.6.RELEASE

New version : 5.2.4.RELEASE

Rabbit mq headers in previous version

```
    MessageProperties [headers={x-first-death-exchange=dms.arkona.exchange, x-death=[{reason=expired, original-expiration=5000, count=1, exchange=dms.arkona.exchange, time=Mon Feb 14 18:03:11 PST 2022, routing-keys=[push.customer.arkona.controller.update.wait.key], queue=push.customer.arkona.controller.update.wait}], x-first-death-reason=expired, x-first-death-queue=push.customer.arkona.controller.update.wait}, contentType=application/x-java-serialized-object, contentLength=0, receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, priority=0, redelivered=false, receivedExchange=dms.arkona.exchange, receivedRoutingKey=push.customer.arkona.controller.update.key, deliveryTag=2407, consumerTag=amq.ctag-1_bYuEGts-Rfk6fqDyIqBw, consumerQueue=push.customer.arkona.controller.update]), amqp_expiration=10000, id=b77509b2-da63-1be0-ffd8-b96cbdc12c89, timestamp=1644890591793}
```

Rabbit mq headers in new  version

````
   headers={amqp_receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, amqp_receivedExchange=dms.transformer.exchange, amqp_deliveryTag=7875, amqp_consumerQueue=pull.parts.transformer.controller, amqp_redelivered=false, amqp_receivedRoutingKey=pull.parts.transformer.controller.key, x-first-death-exchange=dms.transformer.exchange, amqp_timestamp=Wed Feb 16 22:13:14 PST 2022, amqp_messageId=0df5a50e-9c15-ad1d-036d-a98993d2fa92, x-death=[{reason=expired, original-expiration=40000, count=1, exchange=dms.transformer.exchange, time=Wed Feb 16 22:13:54 PST 2022, routing-keys=[pull.parts.transformer.controller.wait.key], queue=pull.parts.transformer.controller.wait}], x-first-death-reason=expired, x-first-death-queue=pull.parts.transformer.controller.wait, id=8c7b4d13-5a20-b430-05fc-492ed98971fc, sourceData=(Body:'{soapActionLookup=opentrack.dealertrack.com/CounterTicketLookup, ticketNumber=161696, truePullTime=2022-02-17T06:12:39Z, currentDate=2022-02-17, secondarySearchSoapAction=null, mode=PARTS_LOOKUP, CompanyNumber=OT2, dmsUsername=DTk@aryA, EnterpriseCode=OTIM, seachEndDate=null, dealerId=1374, messageId={"method":"PARTS_PULL","order_number":"161696","dms":"ARK","request_id":"8347fecf-b7db-40ad-aa0e-fa32615b8c5e","dealer_id":"1374","timestamp":1645078359343}, soapAction=opentrack.dealertrack.com/CounterTicketLookup, dmsHosturl=https://ot.dms.dealertrack.com/partsapi.asmx, closeDate=null, searchStartDate=null, soapActionSearch=opentrack.dealertrack.com/CounterTicketSearch, secondaryDMSURL=null, ServerName=itrack7.arkona.com, currentPullTime=2022-02-17T06:12:39Z, dmsPassword=w34$Rp9, secondaryLookupSoapAction=null, </CounterTicketSearchResponseSearchResult><CounterTicketSearchResponseSearchResult><TicketNumber>161696</TicketNumber><SaleType>R</SaleType><PriceLevel>1</PriceLevel> requestXml=<CounterTicketLookup xmlns="opentrack.dealertrack.com">
           <Dealer>
              <EnterpriseCode>OTIM</EnterpriseCode>
              <CompanyNumber>OT2</CompanyNumber>
              <ServerName>itrack7.arkona.com</ServerName>
           </Dealer>
           <LookupParms>
               <TicketNumber>161696</TicketNumber>
           </LookupParms>
  </CounterTicketLookup>
  , messageXml=<RepairOrderWrap>
     <Dealer>
        <DealerID/>
        <DealerName/>
        <DealerDMS>
           <DealerDMSID/>
           <DMSName/>
           <UserName/>
           <Password/>
           <HostUrl/>
           <EnterpriseCode/>
           <CompanyNumber/>
           <ServerName/>
        </DealerDMS>
     </Dealer>
     <RepairOrder>
        <ID/>
        <OrderNumber>161696</OrderNumber>
        <OrderType>PO</OrderType>
        <Amount>227.90</Amount>
        <OrderDate>20220117 00:00:00</OrderDate>
        <CloseDate/>
        <PrintDate>20220117 00:00:00</PrintDate>
        <DealerAssociateID/>
        <AssociateDMSID>870</AssociateDMSID>
        <Description/>
        <OrderStatus>P</OrderStatus>
        <NumberOfInvoices/>
        <ReadyROData/>
        <IsPaid/>
        <PaidAmount/>
        <IsPaidInKaarma/>
        <IsPaymentRequestSent/>
        <Tag/>
        <MileageText/>
        <InvoiceUrl/>
     </RepairOrder>
     <CustWrap>
        <CAttrs>
           <IsBusiness/>
           <AssignedSA/>
           <Comments/>
        </CAttrs>
        <IdentityAttrs>
           <Attr value="SSN"/>
           <Attr value="DriverLicense"/>
           <Attr value="BirthDate"/>
           <Attr value="Gender"/>
           <Attr value="Language"/>
        </IdentityAttrs>
        <CustPref>
           <Pref value=""/>
           <Pref value="text">Y</Pref>
           <Pref value="email">Y</Pref>
           <Pref value="call">Y</Pref>
           <Pref value="phone"/>
           <Pref value="postal">Y</Pref>
        </CustPref>
        <PreferredComm/>
        
             
  </RepairOrderWrap>
  , dms=ARK, original_expiration=10000}' MessageProperties [headers={x-first-death-exchange=dms.transformer.exchange, x-death=[{reason=expired, original-expiration=20000, count=1, exchange=dms.transformer.exchange, time=Wed Feb 16 22:13:14 PST 2022, routing-keys=[pull.parts.transformer.controller.wait.key], queue=pull.parts.transformer.controller.wait}], x-first-death-reason=expired, x-first-death-queue=pull.parts.transformer.controller.wait, sourceData=(Body:'{soapActionLookup=opentrack.dealertrack.com/CounterTicketLookup, ticketNumber=161696, truePullTime=2022-02-17T06:12:39Z, currentDate=2022-02-17, secondarySearchSoapAction=null, mode=PARTS_LOOKUP, CompanyNumber=OT2, dmsUsername=DTk@aryA, EnterpriseCode=OTIM, seachEndDate=null, dealerId=1374, messageId={"method":"PARTS_PULL","order_number":"161696","dms":"ARK","request_id":"8347fecf-b7db-40ad-aa0e-fa32615b8c5e","dealer_id":"1374","timestamp":1645078359343}, soapAction=opentrack.dealertrack.com/CounterTicketLookup, dmsHosturl=https://ot.dms.dealertrack.com/partsapi.asmx, closeDate=null, searchStartDate=null, soapActionSearch=opentrack.dealertrack.com/CounterTicketSearch, secondaryDMSURL=null, ServerName=itrack7.arkona.com, currentPullTime=2022-02-17T06:12:39Z, dmsPassword=w34$Rp9, secondaryLookupSoapAction=null<InvoiceNumber/><PurchaseOrderNumber/><Total>139.76</Total></CounterTicketSearchResponseSearchResult><CounterTicketSearchResponseSearchResult><TicketNumber>161703</TicketNumber><CounterPersonID>054</CounterPersonID><CustomerKey>1090627</CustomerKey><CustName>EURO MOTORS</CustName><CustPhoneNo>7179200375</CustPhoneNo><SaleType>W</SaleType><PriceLevel>15</PriceLevel><OpenOrTranDate>20220117</OpenOrTranDate><InvoiceNumber/><PurchaseOrderNumber>T093945</PurchaseOrderNumber><Total>471.56</Total></CounterTicketSearchResponseSearchResult></Results></CounterTicketSearchResult></CounterTicketSearchResponse>, lastPullTime=2022-02-16T18:12:39Z, requestXml=<CounterTicketLookup xmlns="opentrack.dealertrack.com">
           <Dealer>
              <EnterpriseCode>OTIM</EnterpriseCode>
              <CompanyNumber>OT2</CompanyNumber>
              <ServerName>itrack7.arkona.com</ServerName>
           </Dealer>
           <LookupParms>
               <TicketNumber>161696</TicketNumber>
           </LookupParms>
  </CounterTicketLookup>
  , messageXml=<RepairOrderWrap>
     <Dealer>
        <DealerID/>
        <DealerName/>
        <DealerDMS>
           <DealerDMSID/>
           <DMSName/>
           <UserName/>
           <Password/>
           <HostUrl/>
           <EnterpriseCode/>
           <CompanyNumber/>
           <ServerName/>
        </DealerDMS>
     </Dealer>
     <RepairOrder>
        <ID/>
        <OrderNumber>161696</OrderNumber>
        <OrderType>PO</OrderType>
        <Amount>227.90</Amount>
        <OrderDate>20220117 00:00:00</OrderDate>
        <CloseDate/>
        <PrintDate>20220117 00:00:00</PrintDate>
        <DealerAssociateID/>
        <AssociateDMSID>870</AssociateDMSID>
        <Description/>
        <OrderStatus>P</OrderStatus>
        <NumberOfInvoices/>
        <ReadyROData/>
        <IsPaid/>
        <PaidAmount/>
        <IsPaidInKaarma/>
        <IsPaymentRequestSent/>
        <Tag/>
        <MileageText/>
        <InvoiceUrl/>
     </RepairOrder>
     <CustWrap>
        <CAttrs>
           <IsBusiness/>
           <AssignedSA/>
           <Comments/>
        </CAttrs>
        <IdentityAttrs>
           <Attr value="SSN"/>
           <Attr value="DriverLicense"/>
           <Attr value="BirthDate"/>
           <Attr value="Gender"/>
           <Attr value="Language"/>
        </IdentityAttrs>
        <CustPref>
           <Pref value=""/>
           <Pref value="text">Y</Pref>
           <Pref value="email">Y</Pref>
           <Pref value="call">Y</Pref>
           <Pref value="phone"/>
           <Pref value="postal">Y</Pref>
        </CustPref>
        <PreferredComm/>
        <Customer>
           <ID/>
           <Version/>
           <CustomerKey>1115218</CustomerKey>
           <TypeCode/>
           <CustomerType/>
           <DealerID/>
           <FName>DORIS</FName>
           <MName>J</MName>
           <LName>KAUFFMAN</LName>
           <ImageUrl/>
           <Indexed/>
           <Valid/>
           <OptedOut/>
           <UpdatedBy/>
           <CreatedBy/>
           <Communications>
              <Communication>
                 <ID/>
                 <Version/>
                 <Type>P</Type>
                 <Value>7174681776</Value>
                 <CreatedBy/>
                 <Preferred/>
                 <Valid>1</Valid>
                 <Label>ct_phone</Label>
                 <Desc/>
                 <UpdatedBy/>
                 <CommPrefs/>
              </Communication>
           </Communications>
        </Customer>
        <LastModified/>
        <StatusCode/>
        <StatusMessage/>
     </CustWrap>
  </RepairOrderWrap>
  , dms=ARK, original_expiration=5000}' MessageProperties [headers={x-first-death-exchange=dms.transformer.exchange, x-death=[{reason=expired, original-expiration=10000, count=1, exchange=dms.transformer.exchange, time=Wed Feb 16 22:12:54 PST 2022, routing-keys=[pull.parts.transformer.controller.wait.key], queue=pull.parts.transformer.controller.wait}], x-first-death-reason=expired, x-first-death-queue=pull.parts.transformer.controller.wait, sourceData=(Body:'{soapActionLookup=opentrack.dealertrack.com/CounterTicketLookup, ticketNumber=161696, truePullTime=2022-02-17T06:12:39Z, currentDate=2022-02-17, secondarySearchSoapAction=null, mode=PARTS_LOOKUP, CompanyNumber=OT2, dmsUsername=DTk@aryA, EnterpriseCode=OTIM, seachEndDate=null, dealerId=1374, messageId={"method":"PARTS_PULL","order_number":"161696","dms":"ARK","request_id":"8347fecf-b7db-40ad-aa0e-fa32615b8c5e","dealer_id":"1374","timestamp":1645078359343}, soapAction=opentrack.dealertrack.com/CounterTicketLookup, dmsHosturl=https://ot.dms.dealertrack.com/partsapi.asmx, closeDate=null, searchStartDate=null, soapActionSearch=opentrack.dealertrack.com/CounterTicketSearch, secondaryDMSURL=null, ServerName=itrack7.arkona.com, currentPullTime=2022-02-17T06:12:39Z, dmsPassword=w34$Rp9, secondaryLookupSoapAction=null, requestXml=<CounterTicketLookup xmlns="opentrack.dealertrack.com">
           <Dealer>
              <EnterpriseCode>OTIM</EnterpriseCode>
              <CompanyNumber>OT2</CompanyNumber>
              <ServerName>itrack7.arkona.com</ServerName>
           </Dealer>
           <LookupParms>
               <TicketNumber>161696</TicketNumber>
           </LookupParms>
  </CounterTicketLookup>
  , messageXml=<RepairOrderWrap>
     <Dealer>
        <DealerID/>
        <DealerName/>
        <DealerDMS>
           <DealerDMSID/>
           <DMSName/>
           <UserName/>
           <Password/>
           <HostUrl/>
           <EnterpriseCode/>
           <CompanyNumber/>
           <ServerName/>
        </DealerDMS>
     </Dealer>
     <RepairOrder>
        <ID/>
        <OrderNumber>161696</OrderNumber>
        <OrderType>PO</OrderType>
        <Amount>227.90</Amount>
        <OrderDate>20220117 00:00:00</OrderDate>
        <CloseDate/>
        <PrintDate>20220117 00:00:00</PrintDate>
        <DealerAssociateID/>
        <AssociateDMSID>870</AssociateDMSID>
        <Description/>
        <OrderStatus>P</OrderStatus>
        <NumberOfInvoices/>
        <ReadyROData/>
        <IsPaid/>
        <PaidAmount/>
        <IsPaidInKaarma/>
        <IsPaymentRequestSent/>
        <Tag/>
        <MileageText/>
        <InvoiceUrl/>
     </RepairOrder>
     <CustWrap>
        <CAttrs>
           <IsBusiness/>
           <AssignedSA/>
           <Comments/>
        </CAttrs>
        <IdentityAttrs>
           <Attr value="SSN"/>
           <Attr value="DriverLicense"/>
           <Attr value="BirthDate"/>
           <Attr value="Gender"/>
           <Attr value="Language"/>
        </IdentityAttrs>
      
        <Customer>
           <ID/>
           <Version/>
           <CustomerKey>1115218</CustomerKey>
           <TypeCode/>
           <CustomerType/>
           <DealerID/>
           <FName>DORIS</FName>
           <MName>J</MName>
           <LName>KAUFFMAN</LName>
           <ImageUrl/>
           <Indexed/>
           <Valid/>
           <OptedOut/>
           <UpdatedBy/>
           <CreatedBy/>
           <Communications>
              <Communication>
                 <ID/>
                 <Version/>
                 <Type>P</Type>
                 <Value>7174681776</Value>
                 <CreatedBy/>
                
        <LastModified/>
        <StatusCode/>
        <StatusMessage/>
     </CustWrap>
  </RepairOrderWrap>
  , dms=ARK, original_expiration=null}' MessageProperties [headers={x-first-death-exchange=dms.transformer.exchange, x-death=[{reason=expired, original-expiration=5000, count=1, exchange=dms.transformer.exchange, time=Wed Feb 16 22:12:44 PST 2022, routing-keys=[pull.parts.transformer.controller.wait.key], queue=pull.parts.transformer.controller.wait}], x-first-death-reason=expired, x-first-death-queue=pull.parts.transformer.controller.wait, sourceData=(Body:'{soapActionLookup=opentrack.dealertrack.com/CounterTicketLookup, ticketNumber=161696, truePullTime=2022-02-17T06:12:39Z, currentDate=2022-02-17, secondarySearchSoapAction=null, mode=PARTS_LOOKUP, CompanyNumber=OT2, dmsUsername=DTk@aryA, EnterpriseCode=OTIM, seachEndDate=null, dealerId=1374, messageId={"method":"PARTS_PULL","order_number":"161696","dms":"ARK","request_id":"8347fecf-b7db-40ad-aa0e-fa32615b8c5e","dealer_id":"1374","timestamp":1645078359343}, soapAction=opentrack.dealertrack.com/CounterTicketLookup, dmsHosturl=https://ot.dms.dealertrack.com/partsapi.asmx, closeDate=null, searchStartDate=null, soapActionSearch=opentrack.dealertrack.com/CounterTicketSearch, secondaryDMSURL=null, ServerName=itrack7.arkona.com, currentPullTime=2022-02-17T06:12:39Z, dmsPassword=w34$Rp9, secondaryLookupSoapAction=null, previousResponseXml=<?contentType=application/x-java-serialized-object, contentEncoding=UTF-8, contentLength=0, receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, priority=0, redelivered=false, receivedExchange=dms.transformer.exchange, receivedRoutingKey=pull.parts.transformer.controller.key, deliveryTag=7869, consumerTag=amq.ctag-dZLHnCtvYWzpTvPM4ASzjA, consumerQueue=pull.parts.transformer.controller])}, timestamp=Wed Feb 16 22:12:39 PST 2022, messageId=2da8985b-9c80-240b-fb29-7294035750f7, contentType=application/x-java-serialized-object, contentLength=0, receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, priority=0, redelivered=false, receivedExchange=dms.transformer.exchange, receivedRoutingKey=pull.parts.transformer.controller.key, deliveryTag=7873, consumerTag=amq.ctag-Fw8OPUahC_jNd--kZIdtSg, consumerQueue=pull.parts.transformer.controller])}, timestamp=Wed Feb 16 22:12:44 PST 2022, messageId=066c4289-5a25-8459-8571-8078421b68d5, contentType=application/x-java-serialized-object, contentLength=0, receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, priority=0, redelivered=false, receivedExchange=dms.transformer.exchange, receivedRoutingKey=pull.parts.transformer.controller.key, deliveryTag=7872, consumerTag=amq.ctag-GYy8qHuHqhZ1s3PyFv5VJA, consumerQueue=pull.parts.transformer.controller])}, timestamp=Wed Feb 16 22:12:54 PST 2022, messageId=5935a433-f7fa-a2c9-f782-d15b4235c91c, contentType=application/x-java-serialized-object, contentLength=0, receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, priority=0, redelivered=false, receivedExchange=dms.transformer.exchange, receivedRoutingKey=pull.parts.transformer.controller.key, deliveryTag=7873, consumerTag=amq.ctag-h6izVs7ziHOH93-M_CBhvw, consumerQueue=pull.parts.transformer.controller]), amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-WdkMr705y_K0iJUOnbGTug, contentType=application/x-java-serialized-object, timestamp=1645078434806}]
  ```
  
  Notice that how spring-integration/spring-integration amqp is adding message body to header and other headers each time the message is passed to dead letter queue
  
  Can someone pls guide us to any setting where in we can disable this repetitive addition of headers . As it is causing the following error in our rabbit mq

caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Content headers exceeded max frame size: 132603 > 131072
````

Basically message headers become so large in size that it exceeds the limits . It doesnt happen in 5.0.6 version

UPDATE :

WE put a custom key like original-expiration which takes its value form x-death header

```
public void processFailedMessage(MessageHeaders messageHeaders, HashMap<String,Object> message)
    {
        if (messageHeaders.containsKey("x-death")) {
            List<HashMap<String, Object>> deathList = (List<HashMap<String, Object>>) messageHeaders
                    .get("x-death");
            //logger.debug(message.get("messageId")+" "+deathList);
            if (deathList.size() > 0) {
                HashMap<String, Object> death = deathList.get(0);
                if (death.containsKey("original-expiration")) {
                    message.put("original_expiration", (String) death.get("original-expiration"));
                    logger.info("original-expiration = "+death.get("original-expiration"));
                } 
            } 
        } else {
            message.put("original_expiration", null);
        }
    }
```

we then use header-enricher to enrich amqp-expiration header

```
public String updateExpiration(HashMap<String, Object> message)
    {
        //logger.debug(message.get("messageId")+" original_expiration = "+(String) message.get("original_expiration")+" initialexpiration = "+this.initialexpiration+" multiplier = "+this.multiplier+" maximumretries = "+this.maximumretries);
        Integer newExpiration = null;
        if(message.get("original_expiration") == null )
        {
            newExpiration = this.initialexpiration;
        
        }
        else
        {   
            double x = Math.log((double)(Integer.parseInt((String) message.get("original_expiration"))/this.initialexpiration));
            double y = Math.log((double)this.multiplier);
            long retryCount = Math.round(x/y);
            logger.info(message.get("messageId")+" "+x+" "+y+" Retried "+(retryCount+1)+" of "+this.maximumretries);
            if((retryCount + 1) >= this.maximumretries)
            {
                newExpiration = null;
            }
            else
            {
                newExpiration = Integer.parseInt((String) message.get("original_expiration"))*this.multiplier;
            }
        }
        logger.info(" NewExpiration = "+(newExpiration!=null?String.valueOf(newExpiration):null));
        return newExpiration!=null?String.valueOf(newExpiration):null;
    }




UPDATE : 

For dlq logic after updating the expiration header we send to the message to a router where it heck if the value of amqp expiration is not empty or empty. Based on that it sends the message either to a dead letter queue or a failed queuue

<rabbit:queue
        name="pull.parts.transformer.controller.wait">
        <rabbit:queue-arguments>
            <entry key="x-dead-letter-exchange"
                value="dms.transformer.exchange" />
            <entry key="x-dead-letter-routing-key"
                value="pull.parts.transformer.controller.key" />
        </rabbit:queue-arguments>
    </rabbit:queue>


@Router(inputChannel="toPullPartsOrderErrorMessageRouter")
    public String processPartsOrderFailedMessageExpiration(@Payload HashMap<String,Object> message, @Headers MessageHeaders messageHeaders) 
    {
        logger.info("{} {}",message.get("messageId"),messageHeaders);
        if(messageHeaders.containsKey("amqp_expiration"))
        {
            String expiration = (String) messageHeaders.get("amqp_expiration");
            //logger.debug("{} {}",message.get("messageId"),expiration);
            if(expiration==null || expiration.isEmpty() || expiration.equals("null"))
            {
                return FromPullPartsOrderErrorMessageRouterFailed;
            }
            return FromPullPartsOrderErrorMessageRouterWait;
            
        }
        else
        {
            return FromPullPartsOrderErrorMessageRouterFailed;
        }
    }
```

```
<int:channel id="PullPartsChannel"/>

<int:service-activator input-channel="PullPartsChannel" 
        ref="syncer" method="onPartsOrderRequestRecievedFromDMS"/>
       

       

<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter channel="PullPartsChannel"
         error-channel = "errorChannelPullParts"  queue-names="pull.parts.transformer.controller" concurrent-consumers="${partsorderpullthreads}" 
         connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory" header-mapper="syncerHeaderMapper" prefetch-count="${partsorderpullfetchcount}" />
        
<int:channel id="fromPullPartsErrorHandler"/>
<int:service-activator id="errorHandlerPullParts" input-channel="errorChannelPullParts" output-channel="fromPullPartsErrorHandler" 
        ref="errorhelper" method="onErrorInPullParts" />
<int:header-enricher input-channel="fromPullPartsErrorHandler" output-channel="toPullPartsOrderErrorMessageRouter">
               <int:header name="amqp_expiration" method="updateExpiration" ref="errorhelper"/>
</int:header-enricher>      
<!-- look at  com.kaarma.syncer.utility.FailedMessageRouter -->
<int:channel id="fromPullPartsOrderErrorMessageRouterWait"/>        
<int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter
        channel="fromPullPartsOrderErrorMessageRouterWait" amqp-template="rabbitTemplate" exchange-name="dms.transformer.exchange"
        routing-key="pull.parts.transformer.controller.wait.key" /> 
<int:channel id="fromPullPartsOrderErrorMessageRouterFailed"/>      
<int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter
        channel="fromPullPartsOrderErrorMessageRouterFailed" amqp-template="rabbitTemplate" exchange-name="dms.transformer.exchange"
        routing-key="pull.parts.transformer.controller.failed.key" />
```

Comment: May we see you flow configuration and how that happened that message sent to DLX contains SOAP info?

Comment: Those extra custom headers must not appear in the dead letter because build-in mechanism is based on a `channel.basicNack()` which does not deal with message, just delivery tag.

Comment: pls check now @ArtemBilan

Comment: Sorry, the update doesn't answer how you do a DLQ logic and how that SOAP info has made it to DLQ'ed message...

Comment: updated the dlq logic also @ArtemBilan. This is my main ask in the question that how come body has come into header with 5.0.6 it didnt use to come as i have mentioned the same code use to work fine

Comment: What happens next after the router in your logic , please?

Comment: Would be great if you could share with us a simple project which would help us to determine the problem clearly. Right now we don't have any clues how extra headers may land  on the message, if you just use regular DLX based on RabbitMQ: https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html

Comment: we are using rabbit mq dlq mechanism through spring-integration

Comment: Well, you don't. This is an artificial DLQ-ing. You just route the message to the `<int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter>`. So, this is a normal message sending, not DLX as it misled us originally.

Comment: Who sends and what into that `fromPullROErrorHandler`?

Comment: @ArtemBilan i now have gien our spring-integration-xml

Comment: @ArtemBilan pls see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this worked for me

```
@Bean
public DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper outboundMapper() {
    DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper amqpHeaderMapper = DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper.outboundMapper();
    amqpHeaderMapper.setRequestHeaderNames(DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper.STANDARD_REQUEST_HEADER_NAME_PATTERN);
    amqpHeaderMapper.setReplyHeaderNames(DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper.STANDARD_REPLY_HEADER_NAME_PATTERN);
    return amqpHeaderMapper;
}
```

i used this bean in outbound-channel-adapter while sending message from spring integration channel to rmq

Answer (score 0):

You can configure `<int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter>` to map only those headers you are interested in. By default it maps all:

```
private static String[] safeOutboundHeaders() {
    return new String[] { "!x-*", "*" };
}
```

See `mapped-request-headers` attribute and docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/amqp.html#amqp-message-headers.

It is not clear yet what was before which had not presented custom headers on the message you send to this AMQP channel adapter. Just because the "copy all headers" logic was there forever.